# Express.js / React.js persistence of state on page refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, session, express

I am currently using Express.js with React.js and I was thinking about how do I make a certain property persist when I **refresh** the page.

Currently my setup is like this:

- I have a default value set for a checkbox (true) for a React component.  User can click on checkbox to make value true/ false.
- I have a timer which automatically logs out the user and destroys the session after a certain amount of time (this timer is automatically refreshed on user interaction - basically based on *idle* time)

Is there a way to tie the current value of the checkbox to the session in order to (assuming the session is still valid)
1) store the value of the checkbox

2) load the current value of the checkbox when the page is reloaded (after a refresh AND use default values for initial load)

Comment: You should use some kind of storage in the client-side or server-side to save the state. I can recommend using localStorage for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save it in local storage and set the time to make the data expire.
Something like this forexample:

```
var timeNow = new Date();
var expires = new Date() //set the expiration date

checkboxGetter(){
if (timeNow<=expires){
var checkboxGetter = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('checkbox'));
}
else{
 sessionStorage.removeItem("checkbox");
console.log("expired")
}
}

checkboxSetter(checkbox){
sessionStrage.setItem('checkbox',JSON.stringify(checkbox));
}
```

Note you can change the sessionStorage by localStorage if you want the data to stay in the browser when you close the browser or for other benifits.

Comment: This is a good answer.  I also ended up using this resource: https://lpasslack.gitbooks.io/react-applications-with-idiomatic-redux/content/docs/03-Persisting_the_State_to_the_Local_Storage.html